# nested map function in a react component -> "unique "key" prop"

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How would i get a proper Key Value in this component:

```
 {var.map((building, index) => {
        const handles = building.buildingVertices.map((point) => {
          return (
            <DrawingHandle
              key={`${index}_handle${point.id}`}
            />
          )
        })
        return (
          <>{handles}</> //<--- how do i get a key in here?
        )
      })}
```

since `<>{handles}</>` does not have a key value, i get the error: `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nested array structure, that is why react does not understand this case. You can use [array.flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to flatten nested array and just return it:

```
{var.flatMap((building, index) => {
    return building.buildingVertices.map((point) => {
        return (
          <DrawingHandle
              key={`${index}_handle${point.id}`}
          />
        )
    })
})}
```

Or you can use full [Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#keyed-fragments) syntax and provide the key:

```
{var.map((building, index) => {
    const handles = building.buildingVertices.map((point) => {
      return (
        <DrawingHandle
          key={`${index}_handle${point.id}`}
        />
      )
    })
    return (
      <Fragment key={index}>{handles}</Fragment>
    )
})}
```

Comment: beautiful! Thanks a lot! i did not knwo about the existence of flatMap!

Answer (score 0):

Why not assign a key to a return div?

```
{var.map((building, index) => {
        const handles = building.buildingVertices.map((point) => {
          return (
            <DrawingHandle
              key={`${index}_handle${point.id}`}
            />
          )
        })
        return (
          <div key={index}>{handles}</div>
        )
      })}
```